# jQuery: pass $(this) to function callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access $(this) when passed to another function as a callback.

I've read through lots of similar questions but just can't get my head around the answers. Is this where proxy comes in, or bind?

I've provided a super-simple example of what I want below:

```
function my_function(callback){

   // Do Something
   callback();

}


$('.el').click(function(){

  my_function(function(){
    $(this).hide(); // How to access $(this) in the callback?
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('.el').click(function(){
  var el = this; // assign this to el
  my_function(function(){
    $(el).hide(); // use el here
  });
});
```